# Ember App.router. "App not defined"

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to route my app for the very first time, but I don't quite understand the logic. I got my templates rendered when putting to my route.js file the following:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('main', { path: '/' }, function() {

    this.route('helloworld', { path: '/'});
  });
});

export default Router;
```

Most of the examples seem to route with function App.router.map. First of all I don't quite understand what is the difference? Are the routes stored inside the app or what. And when I try to add this to route.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  enableLogging: true,
  location: 'hash'
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('main');
});

export default Router;
```

I get: "Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined". So what would be the right approach here and what am I missing out?

Comment: Could you post all content of the `router.js`. Are you using ember-cli?

Comment: @Artych I edited the answer, now there is full contents. Yes, I am using ember-cli.

Comment: Ember-cli uses modules and doesn't use App global variable. Modules way is that you import Ember and define var Router = Ember.Router.extend({ ... })

Comment: @Artych Oh well that explains it. This should be an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, there are 2 approaches to creating Ember application:

1. Using Ember CLI, which is recommended
2. Using globals - App.Router etc.

In Ember CLI you should never access global app variable. So, your `router.js` should look like in your first code example.

`App` isn't defined inside your `router.js`, because it isn't the way to go with Ember CLI.

In Ember CLI you use modules and files split across many directories instead of 1 big file with global variable - `App`.

You should learn more about fundamentals of Ember CLI and Ember. [Ember Guides](http://guides.emberjs.com/) are the best place to start.